# install rEFInd in MacOS Sierra 10.12 Using Recovery Mode

Tags: linux, macos, refind

Hi I am trying to install rEFInd 0.10.8 in MacOS 10.12 with Macbook Pro 15-inch early 2013 according [rodsbooks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html) **Using Recovery Mode** because SIP problem. I just follow step by step and got final result [issue result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PpYQ.jpg). When I type "y", I found the rEFInd installed successfully when I reboot. But it's seems override MacOS(it's remove MacOS).

Any one has a solution? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable SIP first. 
Then try again.
To disable SIP, follow these steps:
Turn off your Mac (Apple > Shut Down)
Hold down Command-R and press the Power button. Keep holding Command-R until the Apple logo appears.
Wait for OS X to boot into the OS X Utilities window.
Choose Utilities > Terminal 
Enter in Terminal: csrutil disable 
Reboot into OSX Utilities window
Then try to install rEFInd 
**Make sure to enable SIP after you're done installing rEFInd!**